# why would freeing calloc'ed memory crash my VC6 project?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, visual-c++-6, gmp

Compare these two largely identical functions. In the first, the memory for `buff` is allocated using _alloca. This works fine. In the second, calloc and free are used instead of _alloca. This crashes.

The weird thing is that I use the calloc/free technique in almost every other GMP wrapping function I have and they all work. Here they don't. Any ideas?

## 1:

```
#define Z(x) mpz_t (x); mpz_init( (x) );
#define BUFF_SIZE (1024 * 32)

BSTR __stdcall IBIGDIV(BSTR p1, BSTR p2 ) { 
    USES_CONVERSION;

    Z(n1);
    Z(n2);
    Z(res);

    char * buff =  (char *) _alloca( mpz_sizeinbase( res, 10 ) + 2 );

    LPSTR sNum1 = W2A( p1 );
    LPSTR sNum2 = W2A( p2 );

    mpz_set_str( n1, sNum1, 10 );
    mpz_set_str( n2, sNum2, 10 );

    if ( mpz_sgn( n2 ) != 0 ) { 
        mpz_div( res, n1, n2 );
        mpz_get_str(buff, 10, res);
    } else {
        strcpy( buff, "-0" );
    }

    BSTR bResult = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR( buff );
    return bResult;
}
```

## 2:

```
#define Z(x) mpz_t (x); mpz_init( (x) );
#define BUFF_SIZE (1024 * 32)

BSTR __stdcall IBIGDIV(BSTR p1, BSTR p2 ) { 
    USES_CONVERSION;

    Z(n1);
    Z(n2);
    Z(res);

    char * buff =  (char *) calloc( mpz_sizeinbase( res, 10 ) + 2, sizeof( char ) );

    LPSTR sNum1 = W2A( p1 );
    LPSTR sNum2 = W2A( p2 );

    mpz_set_str( n1, sNum1, 10 );
    mpz_set_str( n2, sNum2, 10 );

    if ( mpz_sgn( n2 ) != 0 ) { 
        mpz_div( res, n1, n2 );
        mpz_get_str(buff, 10, res);
    } else {
        strcpy( buff, "-0" );
    }

    BSTR bResult = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR( buff );
    free( buff );
    return bResult;
}
```

Comment: what does the core dump say? or don't you get one?

Comment: BTW, _alloca is deprecated, use _malloca instead

Comment: I would guess that mpz_sizeinbase() used on a newly initialized structure should return 0.  With alloca, your buffer is on the stack and will trash the several structures already there (and possibly not crash).

Comment: (massive blush) I think you've hit the nail on the head there @johnny. That _alloca is definitely in 'the wrong place'. Pity one can't tick comments.

Comment: I don't get why _alloca can't be used.

Comment: _alloca _can_ be used. I use it in other places in the project. It's just I wanted to find out why the free of the calloc was failing and @johnny showed me.

Comment: I guess you could have found it quite quickly with the "add logging and dump everything" approach. Helps a lot in such cases.

Comment: yeah, (blush), I would've. And I could've saved S/O some noise too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add logging and dump everything along the way to find what goes wrong. This is usually more efficient than trying to guess.

Answer (score 1):

It may be unrelated, but this type of "works one way but not the other" often indicates a bug that just happens to squeak by in one situation but causes a fatal error in another.

If you suspect a memory overwrite may be occurring you could try allocating an extra 8-bytes in the buffer and writing 4-byte start and end sentinels which you then check for before freeing.

Answer (score 1):

I once spent a week trying to figure out a similar thing.  It was a buffer overrun that trashed the pointer so free was going off into the woods.  Rational purify found the issue in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

calloc could potentially return NULL if there's an error (such as lack of memory).  I would recommend checking the result of any memory allocation function against NULL.  If it is NULL, print a message and then exit(1).

Comment: Even if it is boring, you must always check the return value from stuff like calloc...

Comment: If calloc returned null the crash would occur much earlier.

Answer (score 0):

`_alloca` returns stack memory, so stomping past the end of it may not necessarily overwrite something important. Writing past the end of a heap memory allocation will more likely overwrite something important.

Your code does nothing to ensure that the buffer is at least as big as `res` would be formatted to after dividing n1 by n2 (or vice versa, as I don't know what the actual function does); it only ensures that it has enough memory for an initialiazed `res`, which is probably 1. If `n1/n2` has more digits than that, welcome to crashville.

Answer (score 0):

@johnny pointed out something rather embarrassing, which necessitated a rewrite of the code. (Here's where being able to tick a comment would be useful.)

```
BSTR __stdcall IBIGDIV(BSTR p1, BSTR p2 ) { 
    USES_CONVERSION;

    Z(n1);
    Z(n2);
    Z(res);

    char * buff;

    LPSTR sNum1 = W2A( p1 );
    LPSTR sNum2 = W2A( p2 );

    mpz_set_str( n1, sNum1, 10 );
    mpz_set_str( n2, sNum2, 10 );

    if ( mpz_sgn( n2 ) != 0 ) { 
        mpz_div( res, n1, n2 );
        buff =  (char *) calloc( mpz_sizeinbase( res, 10 ) + 2, sizeof( char ) );
        mpz_get_str(buff, 10, res);
    } else {
        buff =  (char *) calloc( 3, sizeof( char ) );
        strcpy( buff, "-0" );
    }

    BSTR bResult = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR( buff );
    free( buff );
    return bResult;
}
```

In the previous incarnations, the memory was being allocated according to the value of `res` at the point in the code where it contained zero. Thus I was trying to calloc zero bytes and free didn't like it. In the above code, `res` actually contains something that `mpz_sizeinbase` can work with.